# Почему не работает @media запрос?

Tags: css, запрос, media

есть стили для размеров экрана от 768px до 1020px, а есть стили для размеров экрана менее 768px. все срабатывает, если самостоятельно сужать размер экрана. Но стиль для экрана меньше 768 не срабатывают, если его просматривать в специальной вкладке консоли Toggle devise toolbar (обновление страницы не помогает).
пример:

@media (max-width: 1020px) and (min-width: 768px) {
...
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 ...
}

варианты с screen, not screen и чего только еще прорабатывались

Answer (score 0):

помогло: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"